# applying aggregation function on selected rows(longest subsequence) in python

Tags: python, function, dataframe, aggregate, rows

I am working on a Python project where I am stuck on a particular problem and need help.

Alongside is the Input dataframe which I have, and need to apply aggregate function (like mean) on the input sequence to obtain the output as shown in the figure below.  Notice that the aggregate function is working on longest  continuous sequence of A, B, C etc. and not like a customary aggregation function would do. [Click link below for image of the input - output desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b634l.jpg)

INPUT DF Example:

TYPE--VALUE
A   ----    1
A   ----    1
A   ----    1
B   ----    1
B   ----    1
A   ----    1
A   ----    1
A   ----    1
A   ----    1
C   ----    1
C   ----    1
C   ----    1
A   ----    1
A   ----    1

OUTPUT DF Required:

TYPE--AGG_SUM
A    ----    3
B    ----    2
A    ----    4
C    ----    3
A    ----    2

My gratitude for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a creating a group identifier with `shift`, `loc`, and `cumsum`, then aggregate by original `TYPE` and this new `GRP`:

```py
# SHIFT TYPE FORWARD ONE ROW
df['TYPE_lead'] = df['TYPE'].shift(1)

# FLAG WHERE TYPE AND TYPE LEAD DO NOT MATCH (I.E. CONSECUTIVE BREAKS)
df['GRP'] = 0
df.loc[df['TYPE'].ne(df['TYPE_lead']), 'GRP'] = 1

# ASSIGN GROUP BY CUMSUM
df['GRP'] = df.groupby(['TYPE'])['GRP'].cumsum()
df
#    TYPE  VALUE TYPE_lead  GRP
# 0     A      1       NaN    1
# 1     A      1         A    1
# 2     A      1         A    1
# 3     B      1         A    1
# 4     B      1         B    1
# 5     A      1         B    2
# 6     A      1         A    2
# 7     A      1         A    2
# 8     A      1         A    2
# 9     C      1         A    1
# 10    C      1         C    1
# 11    C      1         C    1
# 12    A      1         C    3
# 13    A      1         A    3

# AGGREGATE
agg_df = (df.groupby(['TYPE', 'GRP'], sort=False)
            .agg(AGG_SUM=('VALUE', 'sum'))            
            .reset_index()
            .drop(['GRP'], axis='columns')
         )

agg_df
#   TYPE  AGG_SUM
# 0    A        3
# 1    B        2
# 2    A        4
# 3    C        3
# 4    A        2
```